# How to rotate a 3d vector to be parallel to another 3d vector using quaternions?

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, rotations, quaternions

I have a vector $(a,b,c)$ and another vector $(d,e,f)$. I'm trying to rotate $(a,b,c)$ so its parallel to $(d,e,f)$ using quaternions. I need help understanding how I would do this.

I have so far that a quaternion is defined as

```
q = w + xi + yj + zk
```

so then I have

```
q1 = 0 + ai + bj + ck
q2 = 0 + di + ej + fk
```

But now I'm not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 2):

I guess by "parallel" you intend "pointing in the same direction."

We may as well rotate $(d,e,f)$ in the plane spanned by $v=(d,e,f)$ and $w=(a,b,c)$. The axis of rotation would be around a vector perpendicular to this plane such as $a=v\times w$, which you'd normalize to a unit length vector $u$. Finally, we'd need the angle of rotation $\theta$, which can be retrieved from $v\cdot w =\|v\|\|w\|\cos(\theta)$ by solving for $\theta$.

Then following the [scheme for using quaternions to perform rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), the quaternion you're looking for is $q=\cos(\theta/2)+u\sin(\theta/2)$. The transformation $x\to qxq^{-1}$ moves $v$ to point in the same direction as $w$.

Comment: I don't understand what $u$ is. I can get \theta, but then how does qxq^-1 move v?

Comment: u is the quaternion representing the unit normal to the plane of rotation. It's a quaternion with real part zero just like v and w. X represents any quaternion with real part are (which represents a three dimensional real vector) v moves from v to $qvq^{-1}$

Comment: I think that is just a typo: $a = v × w$ should read $u = v × w$

Comment: @kd88 Actually the only typo was that I used both $u$ and $n$ when I meant the same thing. The point is that $a$ was not necessarily a unit vector.